# R Markdown flexdashboard output not producing ggplotly graphs

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Please help regarding one issue that I have with the output I am getting with R Markdown-flexdashboard. I suppose I am doing something wrong.
I am using the following code in Rmarkdown:

---

### title: "Economy and Population in Croatia 2000-2017"
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggrepel)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)
library(DT)
load("my_work_space.RData")
```

## Page 1 - National level

### Column {data-width=600, .tabset}

#### Croatia 2000-2017: Population and Economy

```
g1
```

#### Croatia by County: Population 2018

```
ggplotly(g4)
```

#### Croatia by County: Economy 2017

```
ggplotly(g5)
```

### Column {data-width=400}

#### Croatia: Economy and Demography by County

```
datatable(data = Datatable_Demo_Econs,
                  rownames=FALSE,
                  options=list(pageLength=3))
```

#### GDP of Regions 2000-2017

```
ggplotly(g2, tooltip = c("Region", "Year"))
```

Here are the pics of the code in the Rmarkdown [code-pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F79xO.png), [code-pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRYxL.png)

However, I only manage to create the first plotly plot (g1) in the flexdashboard. Other graphs are produced via ggplotly (maybe that is the problem?). It looks like some kind of bug for ggplotly graphs in flexdash Rmarkdown script, or I am doing something wrong.
I am attaching the picture to see the almost empty flexdashboard.
[Empty flexdashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9bAv.png)

It is confusing for me that exactly the same code produced the correct and full flexdashboard if I am using RStudio Cloud. I am attaching two pictures of correct and full dashboard produced in RStudio Cloud:
[1. pic: correct flexdash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk1uH.png)
[2. pic: correct flexdash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF0Nj.png)

Thanks

Comment: Hum, if this code appears to work I'm assuming you're copy/pasting everything verbatim. Do package versions differ between your local and cloud install?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your question. Yes the code works, but if I put the code here it reads dashes and # as titles and subtitles, that is why I also put the pictures of the code above: code-pic1, code-pic2. I checked the version of flexdashboard on my R and R Cloud and both have the same version: flexdashboard_0.5.2. Furthermore, If I use dashes instead of # in flexdashboard then I get the graphs but they are not arranged correctly, and if I use # I get the outline but without content. Strange, almost looks like a bug but I suppose I am doing smth wrong.

Comment: It seems that this is a bug related to the version of plotly. I managed to solve this by finding solutions here: 
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1546
This solved the issue: 
Looks like you can workaround this problem by adding config(p, fillFrame = TRUE) to any plot p that isn't shown on initial load